# numpy - is there a way to apply sum() for iterative append to an array

Tags: numpy

For Python iterables, [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is applicable to append multiple slices from left to right.

```
import numpy as np
_list = list(range(15))
print("iterables is {}".format(_list))

print(sum(
    [ _list[_slice] for _slice in np.s_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11] ], 
    start=[]
))
---
List is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

It cannot be simply apply to numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
_list = np.arange(15)
print("List is {}\n".format(_list))

print(sum(
    [ _list[_slice] for _slice in np.s_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11] ], 
    start=[]
))
---
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-a9d278e659c8> in <module>
      3 print("List is {}\n".format(_list))
      4 
----> 5 print(sum(
      6     [ _list[_slice] for _slice in np.s_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11] ],
      7     start=[]

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (2,)
```

I suppose numpy way is something like below.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(15).astype(np.int32)
print("array is {}\n".format(a))

print([a[_slice] for _slice in slices])
np.concatenate([a[_slice] for _slice in slices])
---
array is [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]

[array([1, 2], dtype=int32), array([5, 6], dtype=int32), array([ 9, 10], dtype=int32)]
array([ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10], dtype=int32)
```

## Question

Is there a way to be able to apply sum(). Is there better way other than `np.concatenate`?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [38]: np.s_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11]
Out[38]: (slice(1, 3, None), slice(5, 7, None), slice(9, 11, None))
```

`np.r_` can make a composite index - basically a concatenate of `aranges`:

```
In [39]: np.r_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11]
Out[39]: array([ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10])
```

Alternatively, create the slice objects, index and concatenate:

```
In [40]: x = np.s_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11]
In [41]: y = np.arange(20)
In [42]: np.concatenate([y[s] for s in x])
Out[42]: array([ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10])
```

When I looked at this in the past, performance is similar.

Ways of creating the indices with list join:

```
In [46]: list(range(1,3))+list(range(5,7))+list(range(9,11))
Out[46]: [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]

In [50]: sum([list(range(i,j)) for i,j in [(1,3),(5,7),(9,11)]],start=[])
Out[50]: [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

`sum(..., start=[])` is just a list way of concatenating, using the `+` definition for lists.

```
In [55]: alist = []
In [56]: for i,j in [(1,3),(5,7),(9,11)]: alist.extend(range(i,j))
In [57]: alist
Out[57]: [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Thank a lot for for r_. for ```%%timeit -n 10000``` in my jupyter environment on Ubuntu 20.04 (but VM), ```a[np.r_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11]]``` was ```31.6 µs ± 7.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)``` and ```np.concatenate([a[_slice] for _slice in slices])``` was ```7.17 µs ± 1.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)```. Could be my env specific.